# Django dynamic forms - problem creating a select widget (dropdown)

Tags: django

I am using Django 2.2.

I am creating a dynamic form (unbound to a model). I have managed to create several form inputs dynamically (including inputs accepting more than one choice), but I am having problems creating a select (i.e. dropdown) form input element.

When I render my form using `{{ form.as_p }}` in my template, the select form field is being rendered as checkbox instead.

I have tried **ALL** of the statements below, and the result is the same: the form input field is still rendered as a checkbox.

```
form_field = CharField(label=the_label, widget=forms.Select(choices=CHOICES, required=is_required))

form_field = ChoiceField(label=the_label, choices=CHOICES, widget=Select, required=is_required)

form_field = ChoiceField(label=the_label, widget=Select(choices=CHOICES), required=is_required)
```

How do I force django to render this field as a select (drop down) field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works fine for me

```
CHOICES = (('y','yes'),('n','no'))
class MakeForm(forms.Form):
    form_field = forms.CharField(label="label", widget=forms.Select(choices=CHOICES), required=True)
```

Comment: It turns out that I had an error in the code that generated the data, and it was data for a checkbox that was being generated dynamically, so there was nothing wrong with my dynamic form code :/  I would have deleted my question, but you have submitted the correct answer, so I will leave my question open.